# Grid 1fr height element with scrollable content does not work

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm working with CSS Grid and facing a problem with grid element which has height of `1fr` and `overflow-y: hidden`.

It is `<ul>`, which has a big `<li>` number and must be scrollable.

In FF and Chrome everything works well, but Safari did not cut the list and did not add scroll. Similar problem in Edge.

Parent block:

```
.animatedBlock {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: px(40);
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: auto px(20) 1fr;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Child #1

```
form {
        -ms-grid-row: 1;
        -ms-grid-column: 1;
        grid-column: 1;
        position: relative;
        user-select: none;
}
```

Child#2

```
ul {
        @media screen\0 {
            -ms-overflow-style: none;
        }

        @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
            -ms-overflow-style: none;
        }

        overflow-y: auto;
        -ms-grid-row: 3;
        -ms-grid-column: 1;
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2;
}
```

Here the second child is the target element, which must be scrollable.

Comment: Chrome did it in 2015 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=483473. Why Safari did not?

Comment: Edge does not support the current Grid Layout spec. http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edge confirmed, that they have fixed this issue.

Comment: Here's the Grid Layout implementation status in Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/gridupdate/?q=grid%20update